# как узнать что открытый pipe был удален?

Tags: c, pipes, fifo

Допустим у нас есть именованный канал. Мы его открыли на чтение и читаем читаем читаем. Но вдруг писатель удалил этот pipe(ошибка или ещё что-то). Как правильно проверить что pipe больше не существует.

---

Корректно ли проверять результат read и если он равен 0, то считать что канал отвалился? Если нет данных, то read будет долго ждать своего часа.
Но read возвращает ноль если достигнут конец файла (а pipe по сути тот же файл, ну почти. поправьте если я ошибаюсь.) и это вовсе не значит что файл удален (для пайпов не уверена, поэтому и спрашиваю).
Подскажите как правильно проверить, что pipe закрыт(удален).

Comment: пришел ноль - закрыли пайп. Потом попробовали переподключиться. Если пайп удален, то подключиться не удастся.

Comment: @KoVadim то есть крутиться в цикле и проверять не удален ли канал? а если канал не удален, то сколько  open выполняться будет много раз. мне кажется это очень плохо. насколько это трудозатратно?

Comment: Все зависит от Вашей задачи. К примеру, если в течении минуты не удалось подключиться - шлем письмо админу и отключаемся.

Comment: @KoVadim задача вообще учебная и весьма простая. Мне интересно самой как быть в таких случаях. То есть на протяжении какого-то времени тратиться на syscall. Я думала есть более элегантное решение.

Comment: Можете почитать [man inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify), но  в вашем случае проще всего все же делать `select` с таймаутом и вызывать `stat` для проверки, не удален ли FIFO (Вы же пишете в linux? Там обычно "именнованный канал" так называют)

Comment: @avp через select и буду реализовывать. а вот inotify весьма интерена, надо будет её изучить. спасибо за наводку.

Answer (score 3):

При использованиие функции `read()` Если в канале нет данных будет возврашен 0
а если  произошла ошибка будет возврашено значение -1 и в переемной `errno` установлен код ошибки. Ну тут еще важен момет как открыт канал. В блокируещем или не блокируещем режими.
 Но всеравно функция чтения не сможет указать что файл был удален. 
Поэтому если в программе есть вероятность что канал будет удален. То перед чтением из канала нужно воспользоваться функцией `stat()`  она укажет существует такой файл или нет. И в этом случаи нужно открывать файл в неблокируешем режиме `fd = open("test.pipe",O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);`

Comment: работа с каналом будет идти через select. То есть неблокирующем режиме. Но теперь стало интересно как поступить если он заблокировался. Пробовала открыть файл перед чтением заснутьи во время сна удалить файл. -1 мне не пришло.

Comment: @rubeno4ka Потому что он может быть отлинкован из файловой системы, но с файловым дескриптором в выполняемом процессе ничего при этом не случилось. Это известный казус с логами, например, когда файл уже удалён, но в него по-прежнему пишут и место уменьшается.

Comment: @rubeno4ka, через `select` -- это не означет  неблокирующий режим. Неблокирующий, это когда делаете `fcntl` с установкой `O_NONBLOCK` флага. В результате `read` вернет -1, если читать нечего и установит `errno` в `EAGAIN` или `EWOULDBLOCK`. / Для "отлова" удалений можете почитать [man inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify)

Answer (score 2):

До тех пор пока хотя бы один процесс держит pipe открытой, объект не будет удалён.

То есть даже если FIFO файл удалён (согласно `stat()`), `read()` всё равно может вернуть данные из уже открытой pipe.

Если нет процессов, в которых pipe открыта для записи, то `read()` вернёт `0` (чтобы отметить EOF), если больше нет данных в буфере pipe.

Если ваша задача прочитать данные из FIFO, то открывайте (`open()`) и читайте (`read()`), не забывая обрабатывать ошибки. Никакие дополнительные вызовы не нужны.

Вот пример, который показывает, что можно данные писать и читать даже если `stat()` говорит что нет файла (исполняемый псевдо-код):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from os import *

mkfifo('fifo')  # create named pipe
r, w = pipe()  # "communication tube" between the parent and the child
if fork():  # parent process (the reader)
    close(r)  # close the unused end of the pipe
    fd = open('fifo', O_RDONLY)  # open for reading
    write(1, read(fd, 512))  # read some
    remove('fifo')  # delete fifo
    write(w, b'\0')  # tell the child, the parent removed fifo
    close(w)  # nothing more to say
    wait()  # wait until the writer exits
    write(2, b'read some more\n')
    write(1, read(fd, 512))  # read some more
    if not read(fd, 512):
        write(1, b'EOF')  # read() returns nothing
else:  # child: writer process
    close(w)  # close the unused end of the pipe
    fd = open('fifo', O_WRONLY)  # open for writing
    write(fd, b'data\n')
    read(r, 512)  # wait until the parent removes fifo
    close(r)  # won't listen no more
    try:  # make sure fifo is gone
        stat('fifo')
    except IOError:
        pass
    else:
        assert 0, "shouldn't happen"

    write(fd, b'more data\n')  # write after fifo is removed
    _exit(0)
```

---

Если вас интересует узнать когда имя файла (fifo) было удалено (а не возможность чтения данных), то чтобы `stat()` не вызывать постоянно, можно сервисы такие как [предложенный @avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/530261/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b9-pipe-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd/530366#comment661358_530261) inotify для Linux использовать (на разных системах—разные интерфейсы, но сама возможность на многих распространённых системах есть).